# Which grows faster 2^(2^n) or n^(2n)

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I am quite sure that the former function grows faster. But when I plotted it on Wolfram alpha, the latter seemed to dominate.

In general, if I want to compare f(n) and g(n), can an analysis of log(f(n)) and log(g(n)) be used for analysis of the original functions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`log(x)` is an increasing function, hence `f(x) <= g(x)` if and only if `log(f(x)) <= log(g(x))`.

In this case,

```
log(2^2^n) = 2^n*log(2)
```

This is growing exponentially

But

```
log(n^(2*n)) = 2*n*(log(n)) = O(nlog(n))
```

which is sub-exponential.

Thus, you are correct that `2^2^n` asymptotically dominates `n^(2*n)`.

I'm not sure what you were doing with Wolfram Alpha. The fact that `2^2^n` dominates `n^(2*n)` shows up even for single digit n: `2^(2^9)` is approximately `1.34 x 10^154` but `9^(2*9)` is only `1.5 x 10^17`.

Comment: Thanks John ! I used Wolfram Alpha to plot the functions for a range of values. But I think the free version plots it on a very small range. This led to confusion.